# Shell How to get count value with edge named with dash

Tags: arangodb

This works
`print("Contact count : " + db.contact.count());`

but not that
`print("Is-Contact-Of count : " + db.is-contact-of.count());`

the problem is that the second snippet is about getting the count of items in an edge where the edge name contains dashes.

```
is-contact-of
```

Do you know how to overcome this situation?

db.iscontactof.count() doesn't work
db.isContactOf.count() doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question does not provide a lot of details, but based on the code snippets I would assume that you are writing JavaScript code, probably in arangosh. In JavaScript you can access attributes via the `[]` operator which takes a string:
`print("Is-Contact-Of count : " + db["is-contact-of"].count());`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mpoeter I haven't yet tried your proposition I've just found that one and wanted to close the topic that I created

This works:

```
db._collection('is-contact-of').count()
```